# SDL2 when we create a window with this flags SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN and SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED, SDL2 not working properly?

Tags: c, windows, window, sdl-2

I have created a window using SDL2 in windows 10, with these flags SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED | SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN. After calling SDL_CreateWindow method window get created and maximized but not hidden.

```
 int iWindowFlag = SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED | SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN ;
 const char* program_name = "Player";
 int default_width = 640;
 int default_height = 480;
 SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(program_name, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, default_width, default_height, iWindowFlag);
```

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Comment: it should be maximized and hidden right?

Comment: I've tried your code and it works as it should (window is hidden correctly). Could you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?